Error clr.AddAddReference
Estoy tratando de importar una libreria .dll de .net 6.0, estoy utilizando clr.AddAddReference pero me da error AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'. He desinstalado clr y pythonnet y he vuelto a instalar pythonnet, según sugerencias, pero no resuelve. Pudieran ayudarme. Gracias

Hola Ricardo, asegurate de estar importando el módulo correcto y no otro, lo cual puede pasar por tener instalado otro paquete que use el mismo nombre de importación (por ejemplo, hay un módulo llamado "clr" en PyPI que nada tiene que ver con pythonnet y clr-loader) o por tener un paquete/módulo/archivo llamado "clr" en tu CWD.

Hola. Gracias, pero NO tengo otro módulo. Instalé pythonnet y clr, luego por sugerencias de este mismo grupo los desinstalé a los 2 e instalé solamente pythonnet pues según dice incluye el clr. Y no funciona. Saludos

Crea un VENV en limpio, activalo e instala en el solamente pythonnet y trata de importar clr en ese entorno. Lo de arriba lo decía porque el paquete que incluye (dependencia) pythonnet es clr-loader y se instala con ese nombre, si por casualidad hiciste pip instal clr instalaste un paquete que nada tiene que ver y eso justificaria el error. Prueba con un entorno virtual en limpio, asi al menos se descartan algunas cosas.

Bueno. No ha funcionado tampoco.
